# Find the one city that connects them all

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geography

Below there are 16 cities all across Europe (and surroundings). One of them connects them all.

```
Besançon  |  Ankara    |  Wrocław    |  Katowice
Orléans   |  Plovdiv   |  Munich     |  Debrecen
Nice      |  Chișinău  |  Hannover   |  Linz
Béziers   |  Bursa     |  Stuttgart  |  Lviv
```

You'll have to do the same 5 times. If you find the city, you will be able to check if it's indeed the one we are looking for.

Comment: Ankara isn't in Europe.

Comment: @msh210 This could be a clue. Things like the Eurovision song contest or different european sports competitions use different definitions of what constitutes Europe. Maybe this puzzle isn't purely geography based.

Comment: @msh210, you're right, I have updated the question

Comment: @quarague, nope, it isn't a clue. I just didn't thought about it.

Comment: Is the "one city that connects them all" rot13(n pyhr gb Ebzr, fvapr 'nyy ebnqf yrnq gb Ebzr')?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget, nope. There is more to this puzzle then that

Comment: A [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkjMT.jpg) that some might find useful (coloured by column)... And [one with some 'connections'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL73T.jpg) that didn't lead me to a clear answer... Might spark something in somebody else.

Comment: @Stiv Have you tried road connections, or water connections? Maybe rot13(gur Qnahor Evire)?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Thought about it, but Chisinau was a bit remote to fit with any of the others very neatly...

Comment: @Stiv, you are so close! remember, the earth is round, don't try straight lines :)

Comment: Aha, well I don't have time immediately to learn how to use Google Maps developer tools or find a tool that lets me draw geodesics, so I'm more than happy for someone else with the know-how to take my idea and run with it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of "connect" in this question is:

> If you have four cities, "connecting" them means finding two pairs of cities, whose **geodesics** intersect, and finding the intersection point. To put it another way, we use the cities to make an X shape, and then find the center of the X.

If we use this 'connection' process for each one of the columns, we get:

> 1. [Lyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyon)

> 2. [Istanbul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul)

> 3. [Nuremberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg)

> 4. [Zakopane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakopane)

So now, we get four cities. The obvious next step is to use the connection process again. If we do this , we have

> **Linz**!

"*You'll have to do the same 5 times*"

> We use this connection process 5 times.

"*If you find the city, you will be able to check if it's indeed the one we are looking for*"

> If we take the initials of every one of the cities obtained from our first four connection processes, we get `LINZ`.

Great thanks to @Stiv for helping me with the idea of connections, and the OP for suggesting round lines.

> [image: map]

Comment: "If you find the city, you will be able to check if it's indeed the one we are looking for" => please explain this one as well ;)

Comment: @Lezzup Got it! Also, may you please help me with the imgur link? Somehow it doesn't show up, even if I use the standard convention

Comment: If the missing one is [this place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakopane) then the initials of the places you found sure look handy... (Consider reordering them to match the column order...) You should probably also explain what you mean by 'connect' in your opening line, for ease of understanding :)

Comment: Very good! There was an extra little hint in the text: (npebff Rhebcr -> lbh arrq gb qenj n 'pebff') but maybe that one was too far fetched :)

Comment: By the way, it  was quite a tough one to find 4 cities for which this would work.. and not ending up with some little villages.